# JSON for PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, arraylist

Meu cliente me enviou esse JSON para que eu faça um loop e grave os dados no Mysql. So que não estou conseguindo pois é diferente do que constumo trabalhar;

Alguem pode me dar alguma dica e qual a diferença de um formato para outro.

Erro apresentado é : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 28

foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){

EX do formator que já trabalhei:

```
{
     "ordem_de_servico": [
         {
             "oser_numero_os": 23940493,
             "oser_address_name": NAME;
```

**CUSTOMER JSON**

```
ordem_de_servico:
        {  
           "oser_numero_os":23940493,
           "oser_dt_abertura":"28/03/2018",
           "servico":{  
              "serv_cod_servico":60,
              "serv_descr_servico":"CORTE POR DEBITO"
           },
           "cliente":{  
              "clie_ident_cliente":638617,
              "nome":"MARIA APARECIDA FERREIRA DO NASCIMENTO"
           },
           "unidade_consumidora":{  
              "unid_ident_uc":2436434,
              "logr_nome_logr_expandido":"R JOSE GUIMARAES"
           },
           "faturas":[  
              {  
                 "total_fatura":"88.44",
                 "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-04-01"
              },
              {  
                 "total_fatura":"45.16",
                 "ftcd_mes_ano_fatmto":"2017-03-01"
              }
           ]
    }
```

**My last attempt**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "webservice";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    // Read JSON file
    $json = file_get_contents('oss.json');

    //Decode JSON
    $json_data = json_decode($json,true);


    foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){
        $os = $value["oser_numero_os"];
        $data_abertura = $value["oser_dt_abertura"];

        foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'][$key]['faturas'] as $index => $row){

            $valorParcelas = $row["total_fatura"];
            $sql = "SELECT numero_os FROM os WHERE numero_os = '$os'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "PULAR FATURA"."<p>";
            }else {     
            $sql = "INSERT INTO faturas (valorParcelas, numero_os) VALUES ('$valorParcelas', '$os')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<strong>".$valorParcelas." - FATURA OK"."</strong>"."<p>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error Fatura";
                }
            }
        }
        $sql = "SELECT numero_os FROM os WHERE numero_os = '$os'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "PULAR"."<p>";
            }
            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO os (numero_os, data_abertura) VALUES ('$os', '$data_abertura')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<strong>".$os." - GRAVADO"."</strong>"."<p>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }

    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Esse é o pt.stackoverflow.com ou seja em português traduza sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: @DoutorStephenStrange ok

Comment: Ta bom você mostrou o json e seu código e tudo mais, mas qual o problema? Não tem como entendermos só assim, está dando erro? Se sim, na onde?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 28

foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um teste `var_dump(json_decode($json,true));` e ele estava retornando `NULL`. Esse valor pode ser retornado por vários motivos. No seu caso o motivo era um erro de sintaxe `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. Para corrigir isso, eu adicionei alguns elementos à string:

```
$json = '{'.$json.'}';
$json = str_replace("ordem_de_servico","\"ordem_de_servico\"", $json);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Fiz o teste e o resultado não gerou nenhum erro.

Seu código ficará assim:

```
...

// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('oss.json');

//Decode JSON

$json = '{'.$json.'}';
$json = str_replace("ordem_de_servico","\"ordem_de_servico\"", $json);
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){

...
```